# How to read instrument's range graph

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, instrumentation, graph, lcr

I have an Agilent 4980 LCR meter and in its manual it has several graphs indicating the effective measurement ranges for each scale, like the one below:

[image]

How to read such a graph to be sure that the instrument can effectively measure my device's characteristics? For example, if I have a 500 uF capacitor with an ESR in the range of 0.2 mOhm and ESL 10 nH, how to check these values in such graph?

Comment: Please link to a real device of capacitance 500 uF that has an ESR of 0.0002 ohms.

Comment: I did, actually, but I found a different ESL than expected (half), regardless of how many times I performed the compensation. So I started questioning myself whether I'm in the correct scale or not.

Comment: So, please link to that real device.